# ServiceStack.Redis multi-threading collision

Tags: multithreading, mono, servicestack.redis

I have a ServiceStack.Redis multi-threading collision.  I have a kind of non-standard usage case for ServiceStack where I capture all routes in one "FallbackRoute".  This means there is one service for that one route.  Here is the DTO:

```
[FallbackRoute("/{Path*}")]
public class S3Request  : IRequiresRequestStream{ 
  public string Path{ get; set; }
  public Stream RequestStream { get; set; }
}
```

The Service is:

```
public class S3Service : Service
{
    public RedisUsersCredentials RedisUsersCredentials { get; set; }
    // S3 Request Mutual Exclusion Objects:
    static readonly object syncBucket = new object();
    static readonly object syncObject = new object();

public object Get(S3Request request){
  IRedisClient Redis = RedisUsersCredentials.RedisClient;
  // Do a bunch of stuff with Redis
}

public object Put(S3Request request){
  IRedisClient Redis = RedisUsersCredentials.RedisClient;
  // Do a bunch of stuff with Redis
}
```

Then in AppHost.cs in the Configure block I have autowired redis:

```
container.Register<ServiceStack.Redis.IRedisClientsManager>(c =>
    new ServiceStack.Redis.BasicRedisClientManager("localhost:6379"));

    container.RegisterAutoWired<RedisUsersCredentials>();
```

I got this from posts on how to properly use the BasicRedisClientManager with multi-threading.  But I get exceptions like:

```
multi-request: 581, sPort: 40900, LastCommand: SMEMBERS            TenantOwnerSet:s3devel</Message><StackTrace>[S3Request: 4/1/2015 6:36:50 PM]:
[REQUEST: {}]
ServiceStack.Redis.RedisResponseException: Unknown reply on multi-request:     581, sPort: 40900, LastCommand: SMEMBERS TenantOwnerSet:s3devel
at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisNativeClient.CreateResponseError (string) &lt;IL     0x0003a, 0x00153&gt;
at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisNativeClient.ReadMultiData () &lt;IL 0x000e5,     0x0060f&gt;
at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisNativeClient.SendExpectMultiData (byte[][])     &lt;IL 0x00037, 0x001db&gt;
at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisNativeClient.SMembers (string) &lt;IL 0x0001a,     0x000cf&gt;
at    ServiceStack.Redis.Generic.RedisTypedClient`1&lt;string&gt;.GetAllItemsFromSet    (ServiceStack.Redis.Generic.IRedisSet`1&lt;string&gt;) &lt;0x00083&gt;
at ServiceStack.Redis.Generic.RedisClientSet`1&lt;string&gt;.GetAll ()     &lt;0x0006f&gt;
at S3OL.TenantManager.getTenantOwner () [0x0001e] in     /home/admin/devgit/ols3/mono/src/TenantManager.cs:87
at S3OL.TenantManager..ctor (ServiceStack.Redis.IRedisClient,string)     [0x00084] in /home/admin/devgit/ols3/mono/src/TenantManager.cs:60
at S3OL.BucketManager..ctor (ServiceStack.Redis.IRedisClient,string,string)    [0x00016] in /home/admin/devgit/ols3/mono/src/BucketManager.cs:120
at S3OL.S3Service.Delete (S3OL.S3Request) [0x00195] in     /home/admin/devgit/ols3/mono/Interface.cs:570
at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.lambda_method     (System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure,object,object) &lt;IL 0x0000c,    0x000a3&gt;
at ServiceStack.Host.ServiceRunner`1&lt;S3OL.S3Request&gt;.Execute   (ServiceStack.Web.IRequest,object,S3OL.S3Request) &lt;0x00642&gt;
</StackTrace><Errors /></ResponseStatus></ErrorResponse>
```

Only happens when I have more than one client.  I can hit it repeatedly with one client, and very fast.  If I add a client at the same time it dies in one of these Redis exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IRedisClient` instances are not ThreadSafe and should not be shared across multiple threads. This looks like you're reusing the same RedisClient instance:

```
IRedisClient Redis = RedisUsersCredentials.RedisClient;
```

You should be accessing and releasing a new `IRedisClient` for each request which you can do by accessing the Redis client within the Service, e.g:

```
public object Put(S3Request request){
    base.Redis;
    // Do a bunch of stuff with Redis
}
```

Which works because it [creates a new instance for that Service](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/b6def0bc15f2f66c540a1daad281ca682706e1f2/src/ServiceStack/Service.cs#L89-L93) if it doesn't exist:

```
private IRedisClient redis;
public virtual IRedisClient Redis
{
    get { return redis ?? (redis = RedisManager.GetClient()); }
}
```

Which also [gets disposed if it's created](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/b6def0bc15f2f66c540a1daad281ca682706e1f2/src/ServiceStack/Service.cs#L164) after the Service has executed:

```
public virtual void Dispose()
{
    ...
    if (redis != null)
        redis.Dispose();
}
```

If you don't want to use the `base.Redis` instance that gets created from the configured `IRedisClientsManager` than you must create your own instance within your Service and dispose of it yourself which you would typically create and dispose in a using block, e.g:

```
public object Get(S3Request request)
{
    using (var redis = RedisUsersCredentials.CreateRedisClient())
    {
        // Do a bunch of stuff with Redis
    }
}
```

By resolving and releasing a new `IRedisClient` from a `IRedisClientsManager` each time your service will be using a new client instance that's not shared by any other threads.

Comment: mythz, I understand the concept, but my understanding of accessing the thread-safe instances is where I get confused.  I thought base.Redis was the same client instance as the one in RedisUsersCredentials.  The class RedisUsersCredentials is auto-wired, so it is a new client for each call.  Perhaps this is where I'm confused?

Comment: @tradetree AutoWired only means that the IOC autowires each dependency, it doesn't change the lifetime which by default is singleton scope. See the [IOC wiki for docs about Object lifetimes](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/The-IoC-container#object-lifetime). Note the `IRedisClientsManager` should be registered in Singleton scope so it shares the same pool of clients, but the RedisClient instances must be accessed within each thread as shown in each of the examples above.

Comment: I could post another question, but I think RedisClient.ChangeDb is not thread safe as well?  Even with multi-threading fixed, I get a threading problem if I try and changeDb.  Let me know if I need to submit another question and give more details, or if this is known to be an issue?

Comment: I figured things out with ChangeDb.  I needed application level measures for multi-threading.  Not a Redis issue.