# bulk creating keys in Redis C# - SocketException: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

Tags: c#, sockets, redis, servicestack, servicestack.redis

I'm bulk creating keys in Redis dB under multi-threading environment for some reason in my ASP.NET MVC Web Application.
And I'm using [ServiceStack.Redis](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis) for redis client.

I created a static class for all required redis operations i.e. put,get..
In that static class I'm creating a new instance for redis for each call  which is being disposed once the call finishes (using *using*)
**Code goes like this:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
                {
                    using (RedisClient Client = new RedisClient(_ReplicaHost))
                    {
                        Client.AddItemToSet(key, value);
                    } 
                }
```

However, after some time I get following error:

```
ServiceStack.Redis.RedisException: could not connect to redis Instance at xxx-xxx.xxxx.0001.use1.cache.amazonaws.com:6379 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted xxx.xx.x.xxx:6379
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(IPAddress[] addresses, Int32 port)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(String host, Int32 port)
   at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisNativeClient.Connect()
```

**I looked over the net and found the possible reason is exhaustion of sockets** ([reference](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dgorti/2005/09/18/only-one-usage-of-each-socket-address-protocolnetwork-addressport-is-normally-permitted/))

Since the application is running under multi-threading environment I have to use either of the `PooledRedisClientManager`  or `BasicRedisClientManager` but I am not sure which one to pick in my case and how to implement that there shouldn't be any issue of exhaustion of sockets regardless of multiple operations.

*What should be the correct approach/solution?*

Comment: may I know the reason for downvote?

Answer (score 2):

Don't create a new instance for the Redis Client for each iteration in the loop. Use a [Redis Manager](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#redis-client-managers) to resolve Redis Client instances, e.g:

```
var redisManager = new RedisManagerPool();

for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
    using (RedisClient Client = redisManager.GetClient())
    {
        Client.AddItemToSet(key, value);
    } 
}
```

But there's no reason why you need a new client for each iteration and should just use the same `RedisClient` instance if this was real code.

Comment: I tried using the single RedisClient under multi-threading environment. But, that didn't work. I was getting "null reference","socket not found", "could not connect" kind of different errors.

Comment: I looked over your answer on similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29400937/servicestack-redis-multi-threading-collision and figured I have to use a managerpool and create new client from that managerpool for each and every request. But still won't the sockets get exhausted after few minutes becuz each client uses a new socket?

Comment: @JerryGoyal They won't get exhausted since the connections are reused when they're released back into the pool

Comment: Indeed. I tested with 15 threads but the active clients were only 10. I guess this is the default client buffer in PoolRedisManager. So my doubt is what will happen if I run many more threads which will utilize all the leftover clients of manager pool. Do I have to expand the client buffer at run-time or poolredismanager will take care of it by itself?

Comment: The default MaxPoolSize for RedisManagerPool is 40, anytime you exceed 40 concurrent connections, connections are created/released outside of the pool. This [pooling behavior is explained in the home page](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#redismanagerpool) of each client manager.

Comment: I'm using PooledRedisClientManager  as I require separate R/RW connections. There I noticed that max clients count is 10 even for 15 threads. So it basically blocks on any new connection requests until the next RedisClient is released back into the pool. So, Should I increase the max client pool size from 10 as a safety catch? I know this depends on the current requirements but ur opinion would be great on this.

Comment: @JerryGoyal You'd increase the defaults if you needed to, e.g. if you're running into client starvation/locking issues. But increasing it is fine either way.

Answer (score -1):

You only have a finite number of ports available on your machine that are shared among all process that have to send and receive network data (65535 to be exact) - when you make an outbound connection you have bound to a local port (even though you only specify a remote port you are still using a local port up) - given that you only have 65535 and you are iterating 100000 times I would suggest that you are starving the machine of socket resources and not giving it any time to reclaim those ports.

Perhaps you should only have one Redis client and loop within it:

```
using (RedisClient Client = new RedisClient(_ReplicaHost))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        Client.AddItemToSet(key, value);
    } 
}
```

Comment: did I not mention it? I'm asking about the impact of using single obect for millions of request.

Comment: In which case you need to give the runtime/OS time to reclaim the resources... however I would still suggest that re- using the client, or handful of clients (by means of a connection pool) is the best (and most common) approach

Comment: I understood but I will be using the object in my web application. So i'm worried about how many calls that object can make? and wont there be any time-out for socket if i dont use object for a while?